# Junit to cover Objects.notnull

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

```
public List<ClassRoomListAdapterModel> getRoomListItems() {
final List<ClassRoomListAdapterModel> classRoomListItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
if (Objects.nonNull (classRoomListItemsList)) {
classRoomListItemsList.addAll
(classRoomListItemsList);
}
return classRoomListItemsList;
}
```

Stuck with junit coverage to cover if conditions Objects.nonNull

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code doesn't make much sense. Do you want to duplicate the contents of the list by adding all existing elements back on the same list? Because this is what this `classRoomListItemsList.addAll(classRoomListItemsList);` does. This doesn't test or prove anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way classRoomListItemsList can be null, since it is created right beforehand. So to me it seems you should remove the dead code path (=> remove the null check).

Also, you do realize all this method does is produce an empty ArrayList?